# How can I draw a rectangle around each imageView in an array of imageViews?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, collision-detection

I am making an game in Android Studio.

I have an array of fish(imageViews).

I need to put a rectangle around each fish in the array to begin implementing collision detection of the fishes.

In the function below, I create the imageView, add it to my layout, and then move the imageView across the screen.

How do i draw a rectangle around each fish in the array?

I call this function in a runnable every two seconds.

```
public void spawnFish(){

        Random r = new Random();

        int low = 170;
        int high = 500;

        int start = r.nextInt(high - low) + low;
        int end = r.nextInt(high - low) + low;

        myImage = new ImageView(getContext());
        myImage.setImageBitmap(resizedFish);
        //drawRectangle around myImage for collision detection
        fragment_main.addView(myImage);
        arrayOfEnemies.add(myImage);

        myImage.setX(950);
        myImage.setY(start);


        TranslateAnimation moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(myImage.getX(), -width, myImage.getY(), end);
        moveLefttoRight.setDuration(12000);
        moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);
        myImage.startAnimation(moveLefttoRight);

        Log.d("fishArraySize", Integer.toString(arrayOfEnemies.size()));

    }
```

Here is the runnable

```
    public HUDDrawView(Context context){super(context);
    initMyView();
    }

    public void initMyView(){

        spawnHandler = new Handler();
        SpawnEnemies = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                //Log.d("2seconds", "spawnfish");
                spawnFish();
                spawnHandler.postDelayed(this, 2000);

            }
        };

        spawnHandler.post(SpawnEnemies);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mind me say so, using imageviews for  your game in android might be a bad idea for different reasons, those including:

1. Accesibility.
2. Performance.
3. Scalability.

If you want to develop a small Android Game I would recommend you to use [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) and a secondary thread managing all the logic and drawing.

Nonetheless if you still wanna go with that, you should take a look at the method `getDrawable()` from which you can get the image's bounding box for implementing collisions.

Finally if you still let me and want to try another approach I woule encourage you to look any game framework such as Cocos2dx, Starling or Monogame, you won't regret it!

Comment: If I use a surface view, then I would be drawing the fish bitmaps on a canvas? correct? @LuisMoyano

Comment: in my OnDraw, I am also drawing a hook thats position depends on sensor values that are constantly changing. 

Therefore the onDraw needs to be Overridden and is constantly being called when the sensor values change. 

I tried to spawn the fish in the onDraw as bitmaps, but ran into trouble because the onDraw is constantly being called. I couldn't find a way to create the array of fish and move them across in the onDraw.

any suggestion considering that info?

Comment: As you said, OnDraw need to be called many times (once per frame) So in there you wouldnt want to creaste the initial array since it wouldnt be created many times, So you wouldnt like to created it somewhere else like the class constructor, the oncreate, or the onresume. But what you would like to do is spawning and moving the fishes, how? Well, you can get the elapsed time of each iteration with something like gettimeinmillis() at the beginning of the loop and storing the value, when it reaches 2000 (2 seconds) spawn a fish and reset to zero So it may happen again in two seconds.

Comment: I ended up using an object animator for the imageView. You can then get the X and Y position constantly, and then just drew the canvas in the animation listener function.